# When stop gps in android app

Tags: java, android, gps

I don’t know when to stop my gps.
I use locationManager to operate the gps. 
The problem is that I want to make the same gps work not only in the activity in which I started it but also during I open my menus and options. 
I build a special static class which let me operate on the gps from each of my activities.
I stop the gps by locationManager.removeUpdates in the onPause function in the main activity because I never know if the activity is going to be closed when I open menu and other activities or the system minimize it. 
The solution is to start and stop the GPS in onStart and onStop (or onPause) in each of activities. Is there easier way to solve the problem and stop the gps when the main activity really is closed permanently and will be never again used?

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this issue too and I came to conclusion that the best solution would be just start receiving location updates in appplication onCreate() method and then stop them by timer.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to swap the gps listener in a service and check for existence of your activities. If they are closed, stop the service too.
Communication between service and activities could be done by an easy broadcast, another benefit of this solution... you dont have to register / unregister your gps listener all the time.

Edit:

It is also possible to stop your service if you close your app.
You can implement a isAppActive Flag in your MyApplication base class (extended from Application).
You have to setAppActive = false in onPause() and setAppActive = true in onStart()! Otherwise this didnt work, because onStart() of your next activity started before onStop() of the old one.

Comment: I thought about this bat the weeknes of the solution is that the servis will operate even I switch off  the phone.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF

should solve your problem.